# Wrap part of a string Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this string in jQuery:

```
var string = 'Hello ! My name is John Doe';
```

What I want is to wrap the last word wich is "**Doe**" with a `<span>` tag in jQuery.

Final result : `Hello ! my name is John <span>Doe</span>`

Thanks for your help !

Comment: `String.replace()` would help you.

Answer (score 0):

Without using explicit jQuery, you can make use of the JavaScript string `replace` function.

```
var string = 'Hello ! My name is John Doe';
var newString = string.replace(/Doe$/, '<span>Doe</span>');
console.log(newString);
```

Answer (score 0):

`String.replace()` would help you as such:

```js
var str = 'Hello ! My name is John Doe';
var ns = str.replace(/(doe)+/gi, '<span>$1</span>');
document.body.innerHTML = ns;
```

```css
span { background: #0FF; }
```